# MongoDB Transform element fields into array of values only

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I need help with following thing in MongoDB, what I'm trying to do is to get only marks in reviews into it's own array of values only.

Code i got so far:

```
db.lodging.aggregate([
    {$project:{
        reviews:"$host.reviews",host:"$host"
        }
    },
    {$unwind: "$reviews"},
])
```

JSON Example:

```
 "host" : {
    "name" : "Grimes", 
    "surname" : "Terrell", 
    "gender" : "male", 
    "age" : NumberInt(55), 
    "picture" : "https://api.adorable.io/avatars/285/GrimesTerrell.png", 
    "reviews" : [
        {
            "reviewer" : "Mae Ryan", 
            "date" : "2015-06-01T02:41:46 -02:00", 
            "helpful" : NumberInt(8), 
            "kind" : NumberInt(1), 
            "responsive" : NumberInt(5)
        }, 
        {
            "reviewer" : "Nixon Johnson", 
            "date" : "2016-02-08T10:35:12 -01:00", 
            "helpful" : NumberInt(1), 
            "kind" : NumberInt(1), 
            "responsive" : NumberInt(9)
        }, 
    ]
}
```

This is what im trying to achieve:

```
{
    "host" : {
    "name" : "Grimes", 
    "surname" : "Terrell", 
    "gender" : "male", 
    "age" : NumberInt(55), 
    "picture" : "https://api.adorable.io/avatars/285/GrimesTerrell.png", 
    "reviews" : [
        {
            "marks" : [8,1,5], 
        }, 
        {
            "marks" : [1,1,9], 
        }, 
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your marks' field names are always `helpful`, `kind`, `responsive`, you can use [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/).

Here is a [mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HbrazkR_7A2) for you reference